# Coloring of features in ArcMap 10.1 changes randomly while zooming

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, attribute-joins, maps

I am using the sovereign states shapefile (ne_110m_admin_0_countries.zip) from http://www.naturalearthdata.com/ and joined the attributes with a spreadsheet file that codes many (but not all) country codes into 0,1,2, and 3. I would like to color each of these four codes with a different color using the Symbology->Unique Values tab, but the coloring is not correct. Furthermore, it seems to change randomly if I zoom in and out. The difference between the two screenshots is just the zoom level and you can see how the colors change.

I had this problem several times already after joining tables, but I could never figure out the source of the problem.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2 with closer zoom and changed colors]

Comment: I think you should to turn the same layer on for labels using the same field so that you can see your 0,1,2,3 values coming out.  Also, close ArcMap and re-open it, and turn off or remove all other layers from your map so that you are isolating just this one while you investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out by cleaning up all the missing values due to the incomplete join and the random color changes have stopped.